# Extract data and log file path in sql server using powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm trying to get data and log file information using the below script and arrange the output as per the below xml node..

```
param
(

$ClientName,
$Sourcedatabase,
$DestServer,
$DESTINATIONDB

)


$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $DestServer; Database = '$DESTINATIONDB'; Integrated Security = True"

$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select f.physical_name from sys.master_files f, sys.databases d where f.database_id = d.database_id and
 d.name = 'master'" 



$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)|out-null


foreach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{ 

  $dev1 = $($Row[0])


  $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
  $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
  $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

   $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $ClientName; Database = $Sourcedatabase; Integrated Security = True"

  $SqlCmd.CommandText = "select f.name ,f.physical_name from sys.master_files f, sys.databases d where f.database_id = d.database_id and
 d.name = '$Sourcedatabase'" 



 $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
 $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
 $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)|out-null

  foreach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
  { 


      if($dev1.EndsWith(".mdf") -and $($Row[1]).EndsWith(".mdf"))
     {
      $dev = "<device>|" + $Sourcedatabase + "|#12!" + $DESTINATIONDB 
     $dev = $dev + "|#12!" + $($Row[0]) +"|#12!"
  $dev = $dev + $dev1 +"|#12!"
  $dev = $dev + $($Row[1])
  $dev = $dev + "</device>" 
  $dev
     }


     if($dev1.EndsWith(".ldf") -and $($Row[1]).EndsWith(".ldf"))
     {
      $dev = "<device>|" + $Sourcedatabase + "|#12!" + $DESTINATIONDB 
  $dev = $dev + "|#12!" + $($Row[0]) +"|#12!"
  $dev = $dev + $dev1 +"|#12!"
  $dev = $dev + $($Row[1])
  $dev = $dev + "</device>" 
  $dev
     }
    }
  }
```

the output should be like

|test_restore|#12!testCDC|#12!test_replication|#12!D:\MSSQL\DATA\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf|#12!D:\MSSQL\DATA\Test
_Restore.mdf
|test_restore|#12!testCDC|#12!test_replication_log|#12!D:\MSSQL\DATA\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf|#12!L:\MSSQL\LOG\
Test_Restore_log.ldf

I'm able to get the output...but if a database has more than one data file...then i get only one data file...
please help me on this...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I think You are doing this the hard way... you should try to use powershell properly

Step 1: If you are using sqlserver 2008

Ensure you have sql snappins registered and added:
https://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2011/03/31/loading-sql-server-snapins-into-your-powershell-session.aspx?Redirected=true

you should be able to do this in you ps cmdline (and it not fail)
set-Location Sqlserver:\
or
 Get-PSProvider should return a line with sqlserver in it

this means the you can interrogate sqlserver in a rest/directory style

step 2:
cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\YOURSQLSERVERNAME\default\databases\YOURDATABASENAME\logfiles
replacing YOURDATABASENAME and YOURSQLSERVERNAME (usually your computerName)

now you can run dir this this "directory"
or
 dir | select FileName
 (dir).FileName